# Sending EmailMultiAlternatives in mail_admins()

Tags: django, django-views

I have the below view code snippet and I would like to send email as `EmailMultiAlternatives` to the admins, the problem is...it doesn't render the html tags. 
Kindly assist with some ideas.

```
subject = "A New Feedback"

ctx = {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'message': message
        }

message = ('ecoke/includes/email_feedback.html', ctx)

mail_admins(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message='text/html')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mail_admins`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#mail-admins) is a wrapper around [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail).

In the [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#send-mail) documentation `html_message` is described as the HTML message to be attached to the email where as `message` is the plain text string.

From what you have above you will need to render ([`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)) the message and attach it as HTML.

```
subject = "A New Feedback"

ctx = {
            'name': name,
            'email': email,
            'message': message
        }

html_message = render_to_string(
    'ecoke/includes/email_feedback.html', 
    context=ctx
)
text_message = 'Hi %s, <plain text goes here>' % name

mail_admins(subject, text_message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
```

What happens is that you have two versions of the text; one for plain text one for HTML. As the HTML is not rendered by `mail_admins` you will need to render the template to HTML manually. The HTML message is attached as an alternative as illustrated [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

Comment: what is the purpose of the text_message since I would want the html_message to be the message of the email?

Comment: If the receivers client cannot interpret HTML messages. If that is not a concern you can set `text_message` to be an empty string e.g. `text_message = ''`

Comment: still doesn't render the html!